# Nginx start server command with password in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, nginx-config

I am starting the nginx server that is cert password protected with command that is inside the shell script file which runs in a cron, I want to start nginx for a cron, below i am trying to execute command

```
/etc/init.d/nginx start MYPASSWORD
```

But it does not work for me, please correct me where i am wrong

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The password is asked interactively, so you can not do that. You have other ways:

- Do it manually (/etc/init.d/nginx start and write password when ask);
- Provide a password file using *ssl_password_file*;
- Removing the password of *ssl_certificate_key* file (e.g. *openssl rsa -in original.key -out plain.key*)